# Converting a .pub public key certificate to .ASC

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg, public-key-exchange

I am completely new to the encryption/decryption area and I searched a lot before asking this question (although a very basic one).

We have a user who sent his public key certificate in .pub format. We need to convert it into .asc to be able to import via Kleopatra into our system so that we can encrypt files and send it to him. I have tried to use multiple commands that I found online but none of them seem to work.

Is there a way to do this?

P.S: We use Windows as our environment.

Comment: `.asc` is *probably* an ASCII-armored PGP key. If the .pub is not ASCII armored, import it with `gpg` and re-export it as ASCII armored.

Comment: I tried using the command "gpg --import <Key file location>" and it says "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found."

I googled and this was the only command to import certificates. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: If `gpg --import` prints this error message, you try to import something that is not an OpenPGP key. `gpg --import` allows to import both binary and ASCII-armored key information.